# Android TableRow onClick

Tags: android, onclick, tablerow

I have a few things that I can't seem to get my head around, and would like to get some input.

I have a very simple item manager Android application, in which I have 1 activity, where I'm dynamically creating table rows for a nested table layout to display all the items by means of a cursor (SQLite query).

I'm very new to android development still, so any input followed by a example will be highly appreciated.

Here are the 2 things (as of now) that i need some input on:
1) i want to change the background color of the row user selects just so that it stands out... 
2) after the selection has been captured, i wanted to extract the information from the selected table row...

Side note: I tried to post some code snipit here, but this website wouldn't let me past some space restriction.

Thanks

Parag

Answer (score 0):

firstly , have you considered using a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) instead? [hello-listview](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html)
(there's tools like adapters to insert data automatically into listviews)

every View has properties you can set from the get go through the Layout XML and which you can access and change through the View properties and states so you can change its color `myRow.setBackgroundColor()` and get a property state like current text `myTextView.getText()` .
and for every view you can attach a listener - for example an onClickListener.

usually people here wont answer very basic question so I advise you start with tutorials/books
I really dont mean to sound patronizing (i'm pretty noob myself). 
thats just the case.

hope i could help

Comment: up till now, i have several implementation copies of how i could show the item rows, and have used the automated way you speak off...with the automated approach everything worked fine, but then i wanted to add additional functionality of changing text/background color based on the item type and the only examples i could find were advising to go thru each row and dynamically create views...i have gone through several tuts n most of the ones i ran into were not creating table rows dynamically

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change colors or drawables depending on item state (pressed, focused, selected, etc.) the easiest way is probably the use of selectors: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html.

Exmaple from the above link:

in /res/colors/button_text.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="#ffff0000"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:color="#ff0000ff"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:color="#ff000000"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

in your layout:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_text"
    android:textColor="@color/button_text" />
```